# Why does the first correct answer not get any up votes?

Tags: discussion

The user had a specific problem, and I gave them the answer they needed.

The next answer 20 mins later gets 8 up votes and is marked the correct answer.

Are new people not welcome to answer questions here?

[C scanf behaving unexpectedly with %i to scan dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441967/c-scanf-behaving-unexpectedly-with-i-to-scan-dates/29441970#29441970)

Comment: It looks as though it is a much better answer than your own to me. That could be why.

Comment: @DonkeyKong so correct answer mean nothing?

Comment: There were at least two upvotes in its original, inaccurate state. There are now two more upvotes since the edit. The downvotes were cast on the original answer based on what is stated in the comments (did you see them?) - ideally they should be removed, but that doesn't always happen unfortunately. But, you know, make of this what you will. If you're convinced that this is all because you're a new user, then nothing we say will help you.

Comment: Personally, correctness is a necessary, but not sufficient condition for my upvote. But everyone is free to have their own set of conditions.

Comment: If you can't see that the other answer is a *better* answer, and therefore much more likely to draw votes, then you're doing it wrong.  Surely you do see it but just don't like what happened.  It happens.

Answer (score -23, accepted):

Yes, new people aren't welcome here!

Comment: What would give you that impression...?

Comment: Everybody starts as new people on here, and they're still welcomed until now. And also, if you're focusing into the rep too much, then I'm afraid this is not the correct place for you.

Comment: I have found that here as in most groups you are welcomed to a similar degree as to how welcoming you are. You can make your own problems, or you can have folks cheering for you, all depending on what attitude you  decide to take.

Comment: Your answering your own meta question in this way makes it look like it was more of a rant than a question.

Comment: I started being active in SO last august, so a bit AFTER you started. I'm currently having no problem with my answers. I even get decent upvotes, considering I'm mostly on a lower-traffic tag... I fail to see why you say what you say, and as Pascal pointed out, the attitude you currently display IS NOT WELCOME HERE. But that has NOTHING to do with you being new. More with you ranting about stuff

Answer (score 11):

At the time of this answer, you've received one less vote than the accepted answer.

You have a vote split of `+4/-4`:
[image: OP's Answer]

The accepted answer has a `+9/0` split:
[image: Accepted Split]

You received up votes. If my math is correct, you received `+32` reputation from this particular answer.

---

I am not active in the tags associated with this question, but I can speculate why you received down votes. There are several comments under your answer explaining that an alternative your your solution is possible. These include a link to documentation that *may* show your answer is incomplete. Your two line answer doesn't address these comments at all.

The accepted answer meets the concerns of these comments (using `%i` instead of `%d`). It also goes into a much better explanation of why *their* answer is correct.

In this case, you encountered some questions about your answer. When you didn't address those concerns and another answer did, it appears you were down voted.

New users are welcome (and encouraged) to provide answers. However, I don't think you can be that surprised at a less than stellar acceptance of the answer if you only provide two lines of text and don't address criticism.

Comment: I don't think your math is right.  It's -2 for a downvote, and +10 for an upvote, so that's a net of 32 reputation.

Answer (score 9):

> The user had a specific problem, and I gave them the answer they needed.

To be pedantic, the question reads:

> **Why** is it doing this?

Your answer quite simply did not address this.

Only the OP knows why they did not accept your answer but [it is their decision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/244864) and it is generally recommended that they accept the answer they *personally* found most helpful.

If they genuinely wanted to understand the *"why"* and not just *"how to fix it"* one could assume this is why they did not accept your answer. The accepted answer provides far greater detail and perhaps this OP appreciated a detailed explanation.

As a side note, the fact that you answered first is pretty much irrelevant.

---

> marked the **correct** answer

The user who asks a question gets to accept any answer they choose. It is not an indication of correctness.

> Are new people not welcome to answer questions here?

New people are certainly welcome to answer questions here and we all started out as new people.

Comment: "Your answer quite simply did not address this." Highly relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246665/why-do-people-ask-why-questions-with-the-why-capitalized-and-excessively-for/246666#246666